# Confusion over private chat groups

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, chat

I needed to message a user about something today. I went to [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), found them in the users, then clicked "Start a New Conversation with this user." I wanted the conversation to be private, so I went to the "access options" link presented to me in the room options and was greeted with these two options:

[image: Two given options]

There is no option to make the room private. But then directly below that, there are more options that mention read access and private rooms:

[image: more options]

So what's going on here? Am I able to create private chats? If so, how? Also if so, I think the ability should be moved to the access page.

If I'm not able to create a private chat, **why am I given the option to give explicit read access if everybody has read access anyway**, and why does that option mention the possibility of a private room?

Either way, I think that this should be cleared up on the [Stack Overflow Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) with some sort of Q/A on private chat existing or not existing.

Comment: I think for UX reasons there should be an option to make the room private which is grayed-out. That way it's explicit that you can't make rooms private. And if that's still not clear enough, add a mouseover tooltip that explains that the feature is only available to mods.

Comment: This is bizarre design.

Comment: @RobertGrant Agreed.

Comment: ditto on the bad design/UX

Answer (score 16):

*You* cannot create a private chat-room, only moderators can, for moderation purposes:

[Why are there no private chat options?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143641/why-are-there-private-chat-options)
[How do I make a private chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184130/how-do-i-make-a-private-chat-room)

Options to allow access regardless of the chatroom being public/gallery/private are still always available to the room-owner(s).

So, the information is out there, though not (yet???) added to that faq.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Lets hope they add it to the FAQ. I also think that "read access' shouldn't be a section in the options as it is useless, but that isn't as important.

Comment: So mods can make a chat room owned by someone else private? Can the chat owner then later change the room back to public?

Comment: @Ajedi32: I doubt the owner could change it back. Still, that's a quuestion for a mod, didn't own a private room yet.

Comment: @Deduplicator So the owner can't change it back, but he _can_ whitelist people who can access the room even if it is private?